# Association between json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, jbuilder

I'm working on ruby on rails and trying to creata an Api for my application.

Basically is a blog and i want show in the json response of view.json.jbuild not only the thread information but also all the comments related to the thread in the way that id = threadpost_id

I have this file view.json.jbuilder with this code:

```
json.extract! @threadpost, :id, :title, :text, :created_at, :updated_at
```

And this file comment.json.jbuilder:

```
json.extract! @comment, :id, :text, :created_at, :updated_at, :threadpost_id
```

How can i join them to show the threadpost and all the related comments?

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084117/using-jbuilder-to-create-nested-json-output-in-rails