# How to create a json from a hash using jBuilder in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I have a hash in this format.

@company_details = {org_id1 => [employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4], org_id2 => [employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4] ... }

I want something like:

```
[
    {
        "org_id": "1234",
        "employees": [
            {
                "employee_id": 1,
                "company": "Pepsi",
            },  
            {
                    "employee_id": 2,
                    "company": "Coke",
            },
            {
                "employee_id": 3,
                "company": "Dr. Pepper",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "org_id": "3433",
        "employees": [
            {
                "employee_id": 5,
                "company": "Mirinda",
            },  
            {
                    "employee_id": 8,
                    "company": "7up",
            },
            {
                "employee_id": 13,
                "company": "Hersheys",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried something like

```
//index.json.jbuilder
@company_details.each do |key,value|
  json.org_id key
  json.employees value
end
```

How to customize the value so only some attributes get displayed?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084117/using-jbuilder-to-create-nested-json-output-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
companies = @company_details.reduce([]) do |acc, (key, value)|
  employees = value.map do |employee|
    {
      employee_id: employee.id,
      company_name: employee.company.name
    }
  end
  acc.push({ org_id: key, employees: employees })
end

json.array!(companies)
```

Without knowing much about what your `employee` record looks like, I'm guessing as to the variable names, but you can adjust that to fit your needs.

In short, this will reduce your hash by key-value pairs into an array of hashes, while mapping each array of employee records with only the attributes you need.